# Как сделать так, чтобы программа заканчивалась по нажатию клавиши?

Tags: python

```
if s == "5":
    import time
    sec = 0
    while True:
        print(sec)
        time.sleep(1)
        sec += 1
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: ну программа бесконечно циклирует ,а я хочу чтобы она по нажатию клавиши заканчивалась

Comment: ваш случай - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/how-to-detect-key-presses - решений море, выбирайте наиболее подходящее для вас

Answer (score 1):

*В целях улучшения базы ruSO привожу [перевод ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57644349/13705005), ссылкой на который поделился @Zhihar. Указания на неточности перевода приветствуются.*

---

Это возможно с помощью модуля **`keyboard`**.
Вы можете установить этот модуль командой `pip install keyboard`
Несколько методов отслеживания нажатия клавиши:

---

#### Метод  #1:

С помощью функции [**`read_key()`**](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardread_keysuppressfalse):

```
import keyboard

while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "p":
        print("You pressed p")
        break
```

Это остановит выполнение цикла по нажатию клавиши <kbd>p</kbd>.

---

#### Метод #2:

Используя функцию [**`wait`**](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.wait):

```
import keyboard

keyboard.wait("p")
print("You pressed p")
```

Программа будет ждать, пока вы не нажмёте <kbd>p</kbd> и после нажатия продолжит выполнение.

---

#### Метод #3:

Используя функцию [**`on_press_key`**](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.on_press_key):

```
import keyboard

keyboard.on_press_key("p", lambda _:print("You pressed p"))
```

Это требует функции обратного вызова. Использовано `_`, потому что функция *keyboard* возвращает события клавиатуры в эту функцию.

Функция запустится по нажатию клавиши. Вы можете остановить все хуки с помощью:

```
keyboard.unhook_all()
```

---

#### Метод #4:

Этот метод [приводил уже *user8167727*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44754161/13705005), но я не согласен с его кодом. Я тоже буду использовать функцию [**`is_pressed`**](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.is_pressed), но вот так:

```
import keyboard

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("p"):
        print("You pressed p")
        break
```

Это остановит выполнение цикла по нажатию клавиши <kbd>p</kbd>.

---

#### Метод #5:

Вы можете использовать [**`keyboard.record`**](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardrecorduntilescape-suppressfalse-trigger_on_releasefalse). Функция записывает все нажатые и отпущенные клавиши, пока вы не нажмёте клавишу `escape` или одну из тех, которую вы определили в аргументе `until`, и возвращает элементы списка [`keyboard.KeyboardEvent`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.KeyboardEvent).

```
import keyboard

keyboard.record(until="p")
print("You pressed p")
```

---

**Примечания:**

- `keyboard` считывает нажатия во всей ОС.
- `keyboard` требует root в linux